# R: Factorize one variable in data frame

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have an R data frame with some variables that are stored as numeric but are actually categorical. How do I convert one specific column's data type of an existing data frame from numeric to factor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
dat$col <- as.factor(dat$col)
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame and `col` the name of the column.